# count values of a column group by name in a single row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I want to count how many animals particular person has and count individual of each animal. I have a table with such columns

```
|   name   |   animals  |
-------------------------
|   abc    |    'dog'   |
|   def    |    'dog'   |
|   def    |    'cat'   |
|   abc    |    'dog'   |
|   def    |    'cat'   |
|   def    |    'mouse' |
|   abc    |    'cat'   |
|   def    |    'dog'   |
```

My result should be something like this

```
|   name   |  dog    |   cat   |   mouse   |   Total   |
--------------------------------------------------------
|   abc    |   2     |    1    |     0     |     3     |
|   def    |   2     |    2    |     1     |     5     |
```

Please can someone tell me how can I make a query for that?

Comment: Issues of data display are generally best handled in application-level/presentation layer code. Alternatively, this is a straightforward PIVOT QUERY.

Comment: so what can be the query

Comment: isnt there a solution?

Comment: I've posted a solution to your problem, you can test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *,
       (dogs + cats + mouses) as total
FROM(
  SELECT
    tdogs.name,
IFNULL(ndogs,0) as dogs,
IFNULL(ncats,0) as cats,
IFNULL(nmouses,0) as mouses    

FROM (SELECT name, count(*) ndogs FROM mytable where animals='dog' GROUP BY name) tdogs
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT name, count(*) ncats FROM mytable where animals='cat' GROUP BY name) tcats
ON tdogs.name = tcats.name 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT name, count(*) nmouses FROM mytable where animals='mouse' GROUP BY name ) tmouses
ON tmouses.name=tcats.name

GROUP BY tdogs.name) x
```

I had an error because when I get `NULL` when I count mouses, but I've fixed, this works like you want.

You can try the SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3288/21)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
SELECT name, animals, COUNT(1)
FROM table
GROUP BY name, animals
```

In this way you will obtain the result in a format differend from the one you asked for, but the data are there... to compute the total you could then use php

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
- As mentioned in comments, this way **does not** work. An easier manner could be to do this with a SQL procedure or with a procedural language (such as PHP).

You could make some subqueries to handle this, but I don't think that you could manage it entirely dynamically. I assume your table is named "my_table".

```
SELECT
    t.name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table t2 WHERE t2.name = t.name AND t2.animals = 'dog' ) AS 'dog',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table t3 WHERE t3.name = t.name AND t3.animals = 'cat' ) AS 'cat',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table t4 WHERE t4.name = t.name AND t4.animals = 'mouse' ) AS 'mouse'

FROM
    my_table t

GROUP BY t.name;
```

I did not test this query, this is to illustrate the idea.

Comment: I dont think this gonna run query because sub query cannot get the alias of parent query because sub query runs first and while the sub query has not completed its result parent query is not executed and if parent query is not executed then alias of parent cannot be told to sub query

Comment: From your query it will stuck saying that sub query doesn't know about t.name because that belongs to parent and parent has not executed yet so t.name is unknown